# List comprehension pandas assignment

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, refactoring

How do I use list comprehension, or any other technique to refactor the code I have? I'm working on a DataFrame, modifying values in the first example, and adding new columns in the second.

Example 1

```
df['start_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_d'],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
df['end_d'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_d'],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
```

Example 2

```
df['col1']  = 'NA'
df['col2'] = 'NA'
```

I'd prefer to avoid using [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), just because it'll increase the number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need simply loop, especially if want avoid apply and many columns:

```
cols = ['start_d','end_d']

for c in cols:
    df[c] = pd.to_datetime(df[c],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
```

If need `list comprehension` is necessary `concat` because result is `list of Series`:

```
comp = [pd.to_datetime(df[c],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d') for c in cols]
df = pd.concat(comp, axis=1)
```

---

But still here is possible solution with `apply`:

```
df[cols]=df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x ,errors='coerce')).dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
```

Comment: any way to use list comprehensions and assignment together?

Comment: Yes, it is possible by `df = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(df[c],errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d') for c in cols], axis=1)`

Comment: But  ithink simplier is `df[['start_d', 'end_d']] = df[['start_d', 'end_d']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x ,errors='coerce')).dt.strftime('%Y-%b-%d')`